# FFmpeg Stream RTSP input and save to file at the same time using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am using node-rtsp-stream module to stream RTSP to web with nodejs.
I am streaming RTSP source with ffmpeg, for example [RTSP SOURCE - EXAMPLE](http://rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)

I know that I can save one or many inputs to many outputs but I dont know if there is option to stream the input and save it to file at the same time without executing two process of ffmpeg.

With the following example I am able to stream the RTSP source

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp-url -rtsp_transport tcp -f  mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30
```

On the module is look like that:

```
this.stream = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [ "-i", this.url, "-rtsp_transport", "tcp",'-f', 'mpeg1video', '-b:v', '800k', '-r', '30', '-'], {
      detached: false
    });
    ff =child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [ "-i", this.url,  '-b:v', '800k', '-r', '30', '1.mp4'], {
      detached: false
    });
    this.inputStreamStarted = true;
    this.stream.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      return self.emit('mpeg1data', data);
    });
    this.stream.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      return self.emit('ffmpegError', data);
    });
```

As you can see I am using two process of ffmpeg to do what I want but
If anyone faced with this issue and solve it with one command ( process ), I would like to get some suggestions.
How to stream RTSP source and save it to file at the same time.

for more information about the module I use:
[node-rtsp-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-stream)

Answer (score 0):

try the code: (it will read RTSP and save to a jpg file (overwrite it every 3 seconds))

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var rtspURI = 'rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov';
var fps = 1/3;
//avconv -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov \
// -r 1/3 -an -y -update 1 test.jpg
var ffmpeg = spawn('avconv', ['-i',rtspURI,'-r',fps,'-an','-y','-update','1','test.jpg']);
// var ffmpeg = spawn('avconv',
//   ['-i','rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov',
//   '-r','1/3','-an','-y','-update','1','test.jpg']);

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ffmpeg.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: you have to use avconv instead of ffmepg for the above code, but you can use ffmpeg as well, need to change the parameters.